# Azure functions authentication with ASP.NET Identity and JWT token

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, jwt, azure-functions

I am taking on a new development stack where I am planning to go serverless using the [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/).

I am thinking that my application should use [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) to store user credentials and other details. and he should get authenticated across Identity DB using [JWT tokens](https://jwt.io/).

I am trying to get hold of some examples that might be helpful to see how to implement ASP.NET Identity in Azure functions. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Why you don't use Azure AD?

Comment: @Coding Client insists on using the SQL server db and asp.net identity as we want to leverage asp.net identity capabilities. Any hints on how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

i don't think there is a efficient way to do this. because azure functions don't really have a startup or entry point in the entire app where you can plug in oauth , which is usually done in the mvc or web apps in startup.cs or global.asax.

So this has to divert a little bit from how it's done in a web application

maybe this can be of some help

https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/12/04/azure-functions-http-authorization-levels/

Comment: Thak you. I am aware of the inbuilt levels in azure functions and as you mentioned i couldn't find a place to plug the oAuth thats why i asked a question to confirm whether its possible or not. I guess i will have to develop the module manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something like this recently, i.e. authenticate against JWT access tokens issued by a third party OAuth Server. There's no convenient middleware that lets you do this, so you're stuck with a manual implementation.

The approach I used was to create a [custom input binding](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings) that lets you validate the token and inject a [ClaimsPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netcore-2.2) into the function definition. The resulting function definition looks something like this:

```
[FunctionName("ExampleHttpFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "example")] HttpRequest req, 
    ILogger log, 
    [AccessToken] ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Request received for {principal.Identity.Name}.");
    return new OkResult();
}
```

This does at least separate authentication from the function definition and make things a little more testable.

You need to wire together half a dozen different classes to make it work, but I have written up the detail here: [custom token authentication for Azure Functions](https://www.ben-morris.com/custom-token-authentication-in-azure-functions-using-bindings/). There is also some example code on [GitHub](https://github.com/BenMorris/FunctionsCustomSercuity) that you can look at.

Hope this helps...!